# Spliting an array in php into keys and values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in format

Array ( [0] => A=1 [1] => B=2 [2] => C=3 [3] => )

How do i produce a table with the displayed values as

---

### A  B  C

1  2  3

Where A, B , C are the keys and 1, 2, 3 are the values?

Edit.

My code below is giving "Illegal offset type" error

```
$responses = Array ( [0] => A=1 [1] => B=2 [2] => C=3 [3] => );

foreach ($responses as $response) {
    $key = split("=", $response[0]);
    $value= split("=", $response[1]);

        if($key != "" && $value != "") {
        $data[$key] = $value;    // <<<<< "Illegal offset type" error on this line
    }
}
?>
<!-- displaying the results of the query -->
<table>
    <?php foreach ($data as $key => $value): ?>
    <tr><td><?php echo $key; ?></td><td><?php echo $value; ?></td></tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ? If yes, than post your tried code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this

```
<?php
$arr=array (  "A=1" , "B=2" ,"C=3"  );

foreach($arr as $v){

    $str=explode('=',$v);
    $arr1[$str[0]]=$str[1];


}

print_r($arr1);
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [A] => 1
    [B] => 2
    [C] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split key and array  from values as separate array like below,

```
<?php
$responses = array('A=1', 'B=2', 'C=3');
foreach ($responses as $value) {
    $split = explode('=', $value);
    $array1[$split[0]] = $split[1];
}
print_r($array1);
?>
```

output: http://codepad.org/QdIsKIja

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
$o = Array('a'=>1,'b'=>2);
$keys = array_keys($o);
$val = array_values($o);
```

Comment: the problem is getting my array in the format Array('a'=>1,'b'=>2);

Comment: @user1518597, Did you check Nambi's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21476711/1003917

Answer (score 0):

So you want to display every value of your array, and then every key. Good news, you can do that easily with a foreach loop.

```
$array = array("A", "B", "C");
echo "<p><strong>";              
foreach( $array as $key => $value )
{
    echo $key, " ";
}
echo "</p></strong>";
echo "<p>";
foreach( $array as $key => $value )
{
    echo $value, " ";
}
echo "</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a=array("A=1","B=2","C=3");
foreach($a as $val)
{
 $split=explode("=",$val); 
 $b[$split[0]]=$split[1];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($b);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <?
        foreach($arr as $item => $value){
            $values=explode("=",$value);
      ?>
            <td><?= $values[0]; ?></td>
      <? } ?>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <?
        foreach($arr as $item => $value){
            $values=explode("=",$value);
      ?>
            <td><?= $values[1]; ?></td>
      <? } ?>

   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArray=array("A"=>1,"B"=>2,"C"=>3);

foreach($newArray as $key=>$val)
{
  echo $key."=>".$val."<br>";
}
```